# Connecting multiple queries and passing criteria from one query to another

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to put together a query that will basically run another query on each return.

My current query puts together important info for each client, such as how long an average groom takes and the description of the type of haircut they get:

```
SELECT Query11.petId AS PetID,
       Query11.petName AS PetName,
       dbo_Customer.cstLName AS LastName,
       Query11.lstValue AS Breed,
       qryFindsPetAvgApptTime.TotalAppts,
       dbo_vwPetGroom.pgrName AS GroomStyle,
       dbo_ListValues.lstValue AS Haircut,
       ROUND([AvgPTime]) AS AvgPrep,
       ROUND([AvgBTime]) AS AvgBath,
       ROUND([AvgDTime]) AS AvgDry,
       ROUND([AvgGTime]) AS AvgGroom,
       [AvgPrep] + [AvgBath] + [AvgDry] + [AvgGroom] AS AvgMinutes,
       qryFindsPetAvgApptTime.AvgHours
FROM((Query11
      LEFT JOIN qryFindsPetAvgApptTime ON Query11.petId = qryFindsPetAvgApptTime.PetID)
     LEFT JOIN dbo_Customer ON Query11.petCustId = dbo_Customer.cstId)
    LEFT JOIN (dbo_vwPetGroom
               LEFT JOIN dbo_ListValues ON dbo_vwPetGroom.pgrLengthHairBodyLid = dbo_ListValues.lstId)
                              ON Query11.petId = dbo_vwPetGroom.pgrPetId;
```

I want to add in the average length between grooming appts to the above query info. Right now that is done in 2 seperate queries.
The first one pulls days between appts:

```
SELECT tblTimeLog.PetID,
       tblTimeLog.PetName,
       [ApptDate] - (SELECT MAX(T.ApptDate)
                     FROM tblTimeLog T
                     WHERE T.PetID = tblTimeLog.PetID
                       AND T.ApptDate < tblTimeLog.ApptDate) AS Diff,
       tblTimeLog.ApptDate
FROM tblTimeLog
WHERE (((tblTimeLog.PetID) = [Enter PetID]))
ORDER BY tblTimeLog.ApptDate;
```

And then averaged out with this:

```
SELECT qryTimeLogDiffs.PetID,
       qryTimeLogDiffs.PetName,
       AVG(qryTimeLogDiffs.Diff) AS AvgOfDiff
FROM qryTimeLogDiffs
GROUP BY qryTimeLogDiffs.PetID,
         qryTimeLogDiffs.PetName;
```

Is there a way to pass the PetID criteria from each return into the second query so it adds the average span between appts to the info in the first query??

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server <> Microsoft Access, which are you really using? Tagging multiple conflicting tags means that we have no idea what technology you are really asking about, making your question unclear and difficult to answer. Tagging completely irrelevant technologies just wastes the time of the subject experts you attract that know nothing about the technology you are *actually* asking about. Either way, tag spam can easily end up attracting downvotes and also close votes if they make the question unclear. Just tag the technologies you are actually asking about.

Comment: Also Whitespace and Linebreaks are paramount to making readable text; not just in code. Please get into the habit of making good use of both. Poor/bad formatting is not going to help you or others when you need to be able to quickly read and understand your code. Using indentation and line breaks really helps easily distinguish specific code blocks and sections, and make finding errors far easier when a line only contains 10's of characters, rather than 100's.

Comment: You also appear to be over using parentheses (`()`) in your `FROM`, making your code confusing; none of them are needed. That nested `LEFT JOIN` in the first query looks like an odd choice of syntax as well.

Comment: @Larnu until my post was edited, I had it tagged under ms-access first, because that is what I am working with. Tagging SQL has helped getting answers since I'm writing it in SQL. Thanks for all the other tips, I'll keep those in mind if I ask another question, too bad you had zero insight on trying to find an actual answer to my question. That would have been much more helpful.

Comment: You hadn't *just* tagged [[tag:ms-access]] though, tou tagged [[tag:mysql]] and [[tag:sql-server]] too; that doesn't help us help you as the tags conflict. If you are using Microsoft Access, then that is the only database product you should be tagging.

Comment: IIUC - why not just `JOIN` your final aggregate to first query by `PetID`? You use other saved queries in first SQL block.

Comment: @Parfait without entering the PetID criteria in the 2nd query, I have yet to see it complete the query. The TimeLog table is currently over 34,000 entries and will continue to grow. Unless I could change how I'm calculating the averages in query so that the query doesn't need the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Consider refactoring your second query to avoid the taxing correlated aggregate subquery. One approach involves first running an aggregate query based on a self join to return last appointment date for each PetID.

Even better, turn this query into an action query to populate a temporary table either with make-table query as shown below using `INTO` or regularly cleaning out a persistent table via delete and insert-select query:

```sql
SELECT curr.PetID,
       curr.PetName,
       curr.ApptDate,
       MAX(prev.[AppDate]) AS MaxPrevDate
INTO lastApptTimeLog

FROM tblTimeLog AS curr
INNER JOIN tblTimeLog AS prev
   ON curr.PetID = prev.PetID

WHERE prev.ApptDate < curr.AppDate

GROUP BY curr.PetID,
         curr.PetName,
         curr.ApptDate;
```

Then, base third aggregate query on this temp table and run the difference calculation. Finally, incorporate this query into first query.

```sql
SELECT PetID,
       PetName,
       AVG(ApptDate - MaxPrevDate) AS AvgOfDiff
FROM lastApptTimeLog
GROUP BY PetID,
         PetName;
```